# Close tab dynamically not work rich:tabPanel

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a rich:tabPanel where add tabs dinamically

```
<c:forEach var="tab" items="#{tabsBean.tabs}" >
   <rich:tab  name="#{tab.name}"  >
     <h:form id="#{tab.name}" >
       <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="#{tab.name}" />
            <a4j:commandLink value="X" action="#{tabsBean.removeTab(tab)}" />
       </f:facet>
         <ui:include src="#{tab.path}" />
      </h:form>
     </rich:tab>
 </c:forEach>
```

The troubles are

command link (X) is not show and when i close the tab i would open the @perv tab

How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

`f:facet name="header"` must be a direct child of `rich:tab` (in your code it is a facet of `h:form`, but `h:form` does not support such facet, so it is not shown).

Note also if you are using RichFaces 4.x then you can **not** have form elements inside individual tabs, it is not supported yet, refer to:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11306